# WCF using ChannelFactory.CreateChannel with webHttp behavior

Tags: wcf, wcf-client

I've got a simple REST based service for which I am trying to create a client proxy using ChannelFactory. I want to be without a configuration file so I am trying to do this in code and I believe I have everything I used to have in .config except for the behavior. Can anyone tell me how I can get this config into c# code:

```
  <behaviors>
   <endpointBehaviors>
    <behavior name="InitBehavior">
     <webHttp />
    </behavior>
   </endpointBehaviors>
  </behaviors>
```

Here is the stripped down c# code I have now:

```
var endpoint = new EndpointAddress(urlCommServer);
var binding = new WebHttpBinding();
return ChannelFactory<IInitialization>.CreateChannel(binding, endpoint);
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try this.  You need to add the behavior to the ChannelFactory.

```
var factory = new ChannelFactory<IInitialization>(binding, endpoint);
var behavior = new WebHttpBehavior();
factory.Endpoint.Behaviors.Add(behavior);
var channel = factory.CreateChannel();
```

[source](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/fi-FI/wcf/thread/bc1af6ed-aa34-467f-b4f9-f7dcdb66bdbb)

Comment: Thanks Kirk. I also found WebChannelFactory<T> which adds the correct binding and behavior for me.